# Why does my timeout wait until after the await completes but my log does not?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

If I have something like this setup:

<-- language: lang-javascript -->

```
console.clear();

// noprotect

const fetchSomething = () => new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve('future value'), 500);
});

async function asyncFunction() {
    const result = await fetchSomething();
    console.log('waiting');
    setTimeout(()=>console.log('waiting?'), 250);
    return result + ' 2';
}

asyncFunction().then(result => console.log(result));
```

And my output looks like:

```
"waiting"
"future value 2"
"waiting?"
```

I would expect the `waiting?` to execute before the result completes, but for some reason it waits on the function. What makes one wait but the other execute?

Answer (score 0):

It is a feature of Asynchronous programming.

You have to add `await` and wrap your `setTimeout(()=>console.log('waiting?'), 250);` with a function which returns Promise in order to make it look like it was evaluated continuously.

Something like:

```
await ((ms) =>{
        console.log('waiting?');
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    })(250);
```

Or:

```
await (() => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(()=>{
    console.log('waiting?');
    resolve();
}, 250)))();
```

Mind you, JS has a single threaded run-time engine, so it interrupts evaluation when original script reaches it's end.

And function in `setTimeout(function, timeout)` is evaluated by JS when it has a first chance and time is right.

So your function was interrupted twice and was resumed twice.

Comment: You cannot await setTimeout, since it does not return a promise.

Comment: @NineBerry I added example where it can :)

Answer (score -1):

The call to log "waiting?" is started by a `setTimeout` after the `await` has finished, so after the 500ms in `fetchSomething` have already passed. It will only execute 250ms after `fetchSomething` has returned. That is enough time for `asyncFunction` to return.

If you want to see a different behaviour, start the timer for logging "waiting?" before calling await:

```
async function asyncFunction() {
  setTimeout(()=>console.log('waiting?'), 250);
  const result = await fetchSomething();
  console.log('waiting');
  return result + ' 2';
}
```

Comment: this doesn't address why "waiting" is printed.

Comment: @Rob This question doesn't make any sense. Please be more specific

Comment: "waiting" is printed but "waiting?" is not after the await is initialized

Comment: @Rob It is printed a bit later because of the `setTimeout`

Comment: but "waiting" prints right away, and "waiting?" prints after "future value2"

Comment: @Rob Yes, because it is told to only print after 250ms by placing it in a call to setTimeout with a timeout of 250ms. What do you not understand about that?

Comment: because 'console.log('waiting') prints immediately, the setTimeout waits 250 ms after the 'future value2' outputs.  So if you change the setTimeout to 1, it will still print after 'future value2'.  Have you tried running this code yourself?

Comment: @Rob The resolution of setTimer is not high enough to provide execution within 1 ms. The point is that setTimeout delays the execution of the console output of "Waiting..." but the console output of "future output" is the very next thing that happens because the asyncFunction returns nearly immediately after the call to setTimeout.